# Need help inserting a formula into a variable length column

Tags: excel, vba

I just need to get this formula to insert into a column in VBA.

```basic
Sub Step5Formula()
  ActiveSheet.Range("H5").Formula = ""=A2 & IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1:A100)=-1,""," - " & COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1:A100)+1) & ""of"" &COUNTIF($A$1:A100,A2)""
End Sub
```

I want the formula to calculate how many of a certain number are present and output `1of2` or `2of2` depends on the instance of that number. The formula itself works every day but it doesn't seem to work when entered in VBA.

Comment: The second argument in COUNTIF should be a single criterion, not a range.

Comment: In addition, your quotes are not correct. Try: `ActiveSheet.Range("H5").Formula = "=COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1) & "" of "" & COUNTIF(A:A,A1)"`